# Multiple Tax Query with Meta Key

Tags: multi-taxonomy-query

I am trying to do a tax-query on a hierarchical taxonomy with no tags.  I want to show results for the dealer state and brand being viewed by the user.  For instance dealers in texas that also carry honda.  I only want to show the results if the meta key value of wpcf-paid is 1 for the dealers.

I have the below code, but it does not seem to work.  Any suggestions?

Thank you!

```
$args = array(
'post_type'=>'dealers',
'meta_key'=>'wpcf-paid',
'meta_value'=> '1',

'tax_query' => array(
'relation' => 'AND',
        array(

            'taxonomy' => 'dealerstate',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 'terms' => get_terms( 'dealerstate', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) ),
            'operator'=> 'AND'
        ),

        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'brands',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 'terms' => get_terms( 'brands', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) ),
            'operator'=> 'IN'
        )
    )
);
```

query_posts( $args );

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
'terms' => 'terms' => get_terms( 'brands', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) ),
```

when it should be

```
'terms' =>  get_terms( 'brands', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) ),
```

Unless that is a typo when adding your code example?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed your your meta key is 'wpcf-paid' which would suggest you're using Types to create custom fields.
If I'm wrong, disregard the rest of this message...

I had a very similar query using a value from a custom field checkbox created with Types where I also just needed to retrieve the 1 or 0.

Since Types is reluctant to make things easy outside the loop I ended up going to the database and looking up the value generated when the checkbox was checked. The final query came out like this:

```
'meta_key' => 'wpcf-display-product',
'meta_value' => 'a:1:{s:64:"wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-3ec42d28a86c01314fe62cdd39e5f584-2";s:1:"1";}',
```

Hacky and can probably be improved ( this code is from yesterday and looking for a cleaner solution is on my todo list ) but I just wanted to point out that a meta_value => 1 doesn't work with Types ( unless it's a text field of course ).

If you're wondering then you can find the value generated by doing a sql search in your DB:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'wpcf-paid'
```

Remember to change the table prefix if needed.